# Numerical values and hyphen "-" inputbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, handle

How to accept hyphen char and numerical values on inputboxes?

I have

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles inputBox_1.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.D0 To Keys.D9, Keys.NumPad0 To Keys.NumPad9, _
                 Keys.Back, Keys.Delete, Keys.Left, Keys.Right
                If e.Shift = True Then
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                e.SuppressKeyPress = False
            Case Else
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End Select
    End Sub
```

But it fails when I enter "-" char in the line

```
Keys.D0 To Keys.D9, Keys.NumPad0 To Keys.NumPad9, _
                     Keys.Back, Keys.Delete, Keys.Left, Keys.Right
```

How to let hyphen be written?

Comment: Do you really want to prevent them from typing these values into the box, ever, or would you be content with letting them type then, but then having validation kick up a fuss over out of range values?  I suppose what I'm really asking for here is some more context around your problem so we can work out which solution is best for your actual needs.

Comment: I was thinking the problem better, I think maybe I should validate all after not at the moment user is filling the form, anyhow, Dou you know how to use the code I have in all textboxes?

Comment: You can give a [list of events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y(v=vs.80).aspx) after `Handles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create your custom control and use it wherever you want numeric textbox
Also for number of digit limitation i think there is a maxlength property for the textbox
May the following link answer you question

[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13120/Numeric-TextBox)

Comment: There's really no need to go to all the trouble of creating custom controls when you can just handle validation of the base control.  Also, I don't think that `MaxLength` is appropriate for limiting the size of the number because of the requirement of supporting negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

Right here's a solution. It's a bit more lengthy that I would have hoped, and you can probably speed it up by splitting the textbox text property into single characters and checking them all (but then if you want you code to put letters into the textbox doing so would over right that).

Anyway I tested this and it works fine, and it comes out as 0ms on the stopwatch so it shouldn't provide any noticeable slowdown to the user. Note there is a global boolean variable.

```
    Dim boo As Boolean = True

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim temp As String
    Dim tempchr As Integer
    If boo = True Then
        boo = False

        temp = Mid(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.SelectionStart, 1)
        tempchr = Asc(temp)

        If tempchr < 48 Or tempchr > 58 Then
            If tempchr = 45 Then

            Else
                If TextBox1.SelectionStart - 1 > 0 Then
                    If TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength Then
                        TextBox1.Text = Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, TextBox1.SelectionStart - 1)
                    Else
                        TextBox1.Text = Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, TextBox1.SelectionStart - 1) & Mid(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.SelectionStart + 1)
                    End If

                Else
                    If TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength Then
                        TextBox1.Text = ""
                    Else
                        TextBox1.Text = Mid(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.SelectionStart + 1)
                    End If

                End If

            End If
        Else
            boo = True
        End If

    Else
        boo = True
    End If
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
End Sub
```